# time complexity of while loop in java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, time-complexity

Although I have used only one loop, I don't think the time complexity of my code is O(n).
Could anyone please explain me the time complexity of the code below.

```
public class PatternPyramid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int rows = 15;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = rows - 1;

        while (i < rows) {

            if (j < k) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                j++;
            } else if (j < rows) {
                j++;
                System.out.print("* ");
            } else {
                j = 0;
                i++;
                k--;
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from main question, those `continue` statements are redundant as they are always last instructions loop can invoke in that scenarios.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks for your correction. I have edited my question. Now can you please explain me the time complexity of this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity is `O(n2)`, where `n` is the number of rows.

It requires `n` iterations to print each row of `n` characters. Furthermore, it requires `n` iterations to print each of the new lines.

Ergo, the time complexity is:

`O(n * n + n)`
`= O(n2 + n)`
`= O(n2)`

Comment: thankyou.
can you suggest way to decrease time complexity of this code?

Comment: @mulkraj I don't think there's anything wrong with its current time complexity. It is fast enough even for 1000 rows.

Comment: thank you. Actually I wrote same code in python and i think that i reduced time complexity noticeably.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for(int j=i; j<rows;j++)
        System.out.print(" ");
    
    for(int k=0; k<=i; k++)
        System.out.print("* ");
                
    System.out.println();
}
```

Your code could be transformed into for loops like this, as it can be seen that outer loop run O(rows) times, and the loop for spaces runs rows-i times for each iteration whereas loop for asterisks run i times. Combining them would result in the inner loops running rows times.

Thus total time complexity would be O(rows^2)

Comment: how can we reduce the time complexity further? 
Any suggestions?

Comment: @mulkraj I think its the best time complexity you could have, because for any rows/input, you have to print rows^2 amount of spaces and asterisks.

Comment: @Osama_Abdul_Rehman thank you.